# Цикл выводит результат всех пользователей

Tags: python, django

Делаю сайт на Django.
В профиле пользователя я сделал вывод названия цвета, за который проголосовал пользователь и все отлично работает. Однако цикл выводит результат не конкретного пользователя, профиль которого мы просматриваем, а ВСЕХ проголосовавших.
Как мне сделать так, чтобы был выведен результат определенного юзера?

**models.py**

```
class Choose(models.Model):
    count_black = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="black")
    count_white = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="white")
    count_purple = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="purple")
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Пользователь', 
    on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**views.py**

```
class Profile(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'registration/profile.html'

    def get(self, request, username):
        values = Choose.objects.all()
        # получаем пользователя по username если он существует
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username) # используем для вывода уникальной информации пользователя
        # передаем его в шаблон как profile
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'profile': user, "values": values})
```

profile.html:

```html
        {% for v in values %}
        {% if v.count_black %}
            <h2 class="text_color_light" align="center">
                <p align="center">Voted for black</p>
            </h2>

        {% elif v.count_white %}
            <h2 class="text_color_light" align="center">
                <p align="center">Voted for white</p>
            </h2>

        {% elif v.count_purple %}
            <h2 class="text_color_light" align="center">
                <p align="center">Voted for purple</p>
            </h2>

        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

Что мне нужно исправить? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя немного не правильно сделан запрос

```
values = Choose.objects.all() # здесь ты получаешь все данные из модели цветов
```

Чтобы конкретно делать запрос по пользователю тебе надо сделать такой запрос

```
def get(self, request, username):
    # получаем пользователя по username если он существует
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username) # используем для вывода уникальной информации пользователя
    values = user.choose_set.all()
    # передаем его в шаблон как profile
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'profile': user, "values": values})
```

Что-бы вообще было хорошо, добавь в модель **Choose** **related_name**

```
class Choose(models.Model):
    count_black = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="black")
    count_white = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="white")
    count_purple = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="purple")
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Пользователь', 
    on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='chooser')
```

Не забудь сделать миграции, т.к. модель изменилась

```
python mysite/manage.py makemigrations
python mysite/manage.py migrate
```

Тогда view будет выглядеть так

```
def get(self, request, username):
    # получаем пользователя по username если он существует
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username) # используем для вывода уникальной информации пользователя
    values = user.chooser.all()
    # передаем его в шаблон как profile
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'profile': user, "values": values})
```

Линки для чтения

[related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

[Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/)

P.S. обратил внимание, что у тебя 1 пользователь имеет возможность проголосовать несколько раз и проголосовать за разные цвета, надеюсь ты такие случае отбраковываешь.
Так же для дебага запросов рекомендую использовать django shell

```
python mysite/manage.py shell
```