# Как вывести количество комментариев в статье?

Tags: python, django

`models.py`:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField('название статьи', max_length=200)
    article_text = models.TextField('текст статьи')
    min_text = models.CharField('мин текст', max_length=300)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('дата публикации')
    article_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="img/", verbose_name='изображение')
    views = models.ManyToManyField(Ip, related_name="post_views", blank=True)

    def total_views(self):
        return self.views.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article_title or ''

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)) or ''


class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author_name = models.CharField('имя автора', max_length=50)
    comment_text = models.CharField('текст комментария', max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name or ''
```

`views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    comments_count = Comment.objects.filter().count()
    latest_artiсles_list = Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    return render(request, 'articles/list.html', {'latest_artiсles_list': latest_artiсles_list, 'comments_count':comments_count})


def detail(request, article_id):
    a = get_object_or_404(Article, id=article_id)

    ip = get_client_ip(request)

    if Ip.objects.filter(ip=ip).exists():
        a.views.add(Ip.objects.get(ip=ip))
    else:
        Ip.objects.create(ip=ip)
        a.views.add(Ip.objects.get(ip=ip))

    latest_comments_list = a.comment_set.order_by('-id')[:10]
    return render(request, 'articles/detail.html', {'article': a, 'latest_comments_list': latest_comments_list})
```

В шаблоне я прописал `{{comments_count}}`. В итоге получается, что выводится количество всех комментариев в базе данных, а мне надо в статье. Как я понимаю нужно добавить какое-то значение в фильтр `Comment.objects.filter().count()`, но я не знаю какое.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В дополнение к ответу @[Константина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1372415/231791)

Для вывода комментариев для статей из QuerySet в шаблоне, где производится проход по статьям через `{% for ... in ... %}` выводите кол-во комментариев на основе примера ниже

```
{% for article in latest_artiсles_list %}
    <!-- Ваш html код вывода блока статьи до кол-ва коментариев -->
    {{ article.comment_set.count }}
    <!-- Ваш html код вывода блока статьи после кол-ва комментариев -->
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Получаем текущую статью по id

```py
article = Article.objects.get(pk=<pk>)
```

Имея на руках объект статьи можем получить список всех комментов т.к. вы указали связь в модели

```py
comments = article.comment_set.count()
```

Конечно для таких манипуляций лучше использовать
[related_name](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1367755/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/1367958#:%7E:text=%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-,related_name,-Making%20queries)

Comment: А параметр pk это что? Он у меня подчёркивается красным и как его передать?

Comment: это id статьи к которой вы обращаетесь

Comment: А что мне нужно там указывать, если мне надо не определённую статью, а на все

Comment: Из вашего заголовка я Как вывести количество комментариев в определённой статье? Соответственно этот запрос сделает то, что вы хотите.

Comment: А ну я наверно не правильно задал вопрос. Мне нужно чтобы там где перечисляются статьи была показана цифра сколько в это статье комментариев.